# Can a thief who acquires a credit card number trace this back to PayPal and exploit the PayPal account?

Tags: credit-card, scams, paypal

A friend reports that their credit card number was stolen and used to purchase an iPhone.

They also report that nearly simultaneously, a large transfer from their bank account to their own PayPal account  was requested. Both the bank account and the credit card number had previously been linked to their PayPal account.

Can a mere stolen credit card number (which happens all the time) be used to link back to a PayPal account and manipulate it in this manner? Or was something else entirely done?

Searches have not turned up any other reports of this happening, but I may not know the proper terms to search for.

My hunch is that the PayPal account was compromised, not the credit card.

Comment: Your hunch is prorably right. It's much easier to hijack PP accaount than to waste time and effort to trace PP account assosiated with certain CC number and THEN try to hijack it.

Comment: Was the transfer from your friend's bank account to _their_ PayPal account or a different one? If it _was_ to their PayPal account (and, presumably, was then sent elsewhere), that would support the PayPal account being compromised. If it was to a _different_ PayPal account, was it an actual _Credit Card_ number that was stolen, or could it have been something like a Visa _Debit_ card, that has a "credit-card-like" number, but is tied to a bank account?

Comment: @TripeHound it was to their own PayPal account. Sorry that I wasn't clear. I have edited the question. Apparently it is a *credit* not *debit* card.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Then that sounds increasingly like the PayPal account was hijacked.